# Microsoft Monaco Editor in browser get value of line

Tags: javascript, browser, monaco-editor

I have been working through using the browser based version of the Microsoft Monaco Editor, I can't find any documentation or any examples in the playground that tell you how to get the value of a specific line of in the editor.

For example:

```
class Example {
    private m:number;

    public met(): string {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

Line 2 would be `private m:number;`.

How would you get the value of that line or even part of the line and then change it's value using code.  I want to put that action into a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no such built-in feature in monaco as I do not found it. but i am doing that using following code:

```
editor.addAction({
        id: 'some_id',
        label: 'label',
        keybindings: [monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | monaco.KeyCode.KEY_C],
        run: function(ed) {
            var position = ed.getPosition();
            var text = ed.getValue(position);
            var splitedText=text.split("\n");
            var line = splitedText[position.lineNumber-1];

            // now you have current line
            // you can also get any other line
            // and do something with that line

            splitedText[position.lineNumber-1]= _newLineText_
            ed.setValue(splitedText.join("\n"));
            ed.setPosition(position); // to return the pointer to the a position before editing text

            return null;
        },
        enablement: {
            textFocus: true,
        }
    });
```

this method is good for small file but for large file the whole editor will re highlights and that a bad thing.

Comment: Thank you I will definitely give it a try and accept once I test it out.

Comment: Just a side question is there a way to trigger the commands from the monaco editor using your own events or override the default key board short cuts using the the javascript?

Comment: Do you want to bind keyboard shortcut in monaco for this check [that](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#interacting-with-the-editor-listening-to-key-events)

Answer (score 13):

Getting the content of a line is actually very easy: [`IModel.getLineContent()`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.imodel.html#getlinecontent)

```
line = model.getLineContent(3);
```

Note that the line numbers start with 1 when using `getLineContent()`.

Replacing the text is a bit more complicated, but you could apply edit operations:

- Through the editor: [`IStandaloneCodeEditor.executeEdits`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.istandalonecodeeditor.html#executeedits)
- Through the model: [`IModel.applyEdits()`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.imodel.html#applyedits) and [`IModel.pushEditOperations()`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.imodel.html#pusheditoperations).

The `applyEdits` won't add the edits to the undo stack and is thus discouraged. However all three use the same interface for the actual changes: [`IIdentifiedSingleEditOperation`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.iidentifiedsingleeditoperation.html) so the actual calls won't be very different, so I'll just show it with `pushEditOperations()`:

```
model.pushEditOperations(
    [],
    [
        {
            forceMoveMarkers: true,
            identifier: "mychange",
            range: {
                startLineNumber: lineNo,
                endLineNumber: lineNo,
                startColumn: 1,
                endColumn: line.length + 1,
            },
            text: "this will be the new text there"
        },
    ],
    []
);
```

If you want to test it out on the Monaco playground I used this code (adapted from the "Adding Actions" example):

```
var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: [
        '',
        'class Example {',
        '\tprivate m:number;',
        '',
        '\tpublic met(): string {',
        '\t\treturn "Hello world!";',
        '\t}',
        '}'
    ].join('\n'),
    language: "typescript"
});
var model = editor.getModel();

editor.addAction({
    id: 'my-unique-id',
    label: 'Replace the second line',
    keybindings: [ monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | monaco.KeyCode.F10 ],
    contextMenuGroupId: 'custom',
    contextMenuOrder: 1,
    run: function(ed) {
        var lineNo = 3;
        var line = model.getLineContent(lineNo);
        console.log("These were the contents of the second line before I replaced them:", line);
        model.pushEditOperations(
            [],
            [
                {
                    forceMoveMarkers: true,
                    identifier: "mychange",
                    range: {
                        startLineNumber: lineNo,
                        endLineNumber: lineNo,
                        startColumn: 1,
                        endColumn: line.length + 1,
                    },
                    text: "this will be the new text there"
                },
            ],
            []
        );
    }
});
```

In this case you can run the action by:

- pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>
- by right-clicking on the editor and selecting "Replace the second line" (at least if you haven't hidden the editors context menu).